# How to validate list of UUID's AND return UUID Version?

Tags: python, uuid

I'm needing to both validate a list of UUID's as well as determine the version. For example, using h[ttps://www.beautifyconverter.com/uuid-validator.php](https://www.beautifyconverter.com/uuid-validator.php) and entering 25CCCA6F-1568-473E-BFED-EC08C31532C6 I can determine that it is both valid, and version 4. I see from https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/12614/Validating-a-uuid4-with-Python- and [How to determine if a string is a valid v4 UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989481/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-valid-v4-uuid) that the UUID module can validate one at a time, or test for a particular version, but not sure if UUID will test for all 4 versions and return the version.

Comment: You've dealed with the hardest part. Now go find out how to loop in python, and to break from loop once a true boolean value is found for the `uuid` validation function.

Answer (score 17):

Here is how I would iterative over a list of potential UUIDs and return a parallel list with either the version number (if valid) or `None` otherwise.

Note especially that the `UUID` constructor accepts UUID strings of any version. If the string is valid, you can query the `.version` member to determine the version.

```
from uuid import UUID


def version_uuid(uuid):
    try:
        return UUID(uuid).version
    except ValueError:
        return None

def version_list(l):
    return [version_uuid(uuid) for uuid in l]

if __name__=="__main__":
    uuids = (
        '0d14fbaa-8cd6-11e7-b2ed-28d244cd6e76',
        '6fa459ea-ee8a-3ca4-894e-db77e160355e',
        '16583cd3-8361-4fe6-a345-e1f546b86b74',
        '886313e1-3b8a-5372-9b90-0c9aee199e5d',
        '0d14fbaa-8cd6-11e7-b2ed-28d244cd6e7',
        '6fa459ea-ee8a-3ca4-894e-db77e160355',
        '16583cd3-8361-4fe6-a345-e1f546b86b7',
        '886313e1-3b8a-5372-9b90-0c9aee199e5',
        '481A8DE5-F0D1-E211-B425-E41F134196DA',
    )
    assert version_list(uuids) == [1,3,4,5,None,None,None,None,14]
```

Comment: interesting, but there's a twist. The list I'm checking includes some UUID's that don't appear to conform to any format: 481A8DE5-F0D1-E211-B425-E41F134196DA. Note the "E" in the position normally where the version is.

Comment: My code (correctly, I assert) returns 14 for the version number of that UUID. What behavior did you expect?

Comment: when I try your solution, blank returns with your sample data, when I add 481A8DE5-F0D1-E211-B425-E41F134196DA to the lists, traceback failure. Python 2.7.13 64 bit

Answer (score 7):

```
def validate_uuid4(uuid_string):

    try:
        val = UUID(uuid_string, version=4)
    except ValueError:
        # If it's a value error, then the string 
        # is not a valid hex code for a UUID.
        return False

    return True
```

You can use the above function to go through your list of uuid string and it will tell you whether a particular string in the list if a valid version 4 uuid

Comment: This will pass valid UUID with a version different from 4. `UUID(x, version=4)` converts x to a UUIDv4 successfully even if x is a UUIDv1 string, for example.

Comment: This does not work if uuid_string has a version other than 4.