# Django is-instance is not working properly For UUID

Tags: django, uuid

I have UUID4 value= "2626df07-1854-4ff1-9296-fa43bc896950"

for this value am trying

```
import uuid
print((isinstance(value, uuid.UUID)))
```

Result is:- False
can anyone please explain me the reason behind this.
Note:-value is a proper UUId4

Comment: With `value= "2626df07-1854-4ff1-9296-fa43bc896950"`, `value` is a `str`. That's not an instance of `UUID`.

Comment: @deceze so how can i check with a string that upcoming value is UUID

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45943934/476